# Routing error (missing template)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rout.rb

```
map.logout 'logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'  

map.login 'login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
```

In sessions control have destroy method, but when I type /logout it's say: Missing template session/destroy.erb in view path app/view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an action but you don't have a view. You can either make a view destroy.html.erb, render :action => 'index' (for example) or more likely redirect_to :action => 'index' after the destroy action has completed.

Comment: I must make a destroy.html.erb view? I skip this step, and put redirect in the control, but nothing changed When I make destroy.html.erb, i got a blank page.

Comment: It will be blank until you add some content to the view file. Really though it's more common to redirect_to somewhere after destroy.

Answer (score 0):

Add a file name `destroy.html.erb` to the folder `app/views/sessions`.

Note that `sessions` is plural (I think you mis-typed the `session` in the error message you posted?)